# Membership Details Report doubt about Grouping

Tags: civimember, civireport

In the Membership Detail Report there is the tab 'Grouping'. Is this tab really necessary?

Every membership has an unique id so it doesn't seems logic to group by this field.

I did some test in my civicrm and in dmaster and in both sites the results were the same whether or not the grouping field was selected.

So, it is useful? Or I'm mistaking something?

Answer (score 1):

I think it would only make a difference if you have multi-value custom fields attached to your contact & included in the report